# Parsing out part of string in Google Refine - error message

Tags: java, regex, google-refine

I am cleaning a dataset using Google Refine. I have one column with dates in the mm/dd/yyyy format. I want to create a new column in which mm/dd/yyyy is replaced by yyyy only.

I have tried

```
value.replace(/.+(\d\d\d\d)\*/, /$1/)
```

and what showed up was

> Error: replace expects 3 strings, or 1 string, 1 regex, and 1 string

Why does this error show up? Thank you for helping a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are just dates in that regular format, the easy solution is:

```
value.split('/')[2]
```

if you need to pluck the date out of the middle of a long string or just have a warped desire to mess with regex :-) then you can use

```
value.replace(/([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\D([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])\D(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])/, "$3")
```

BTW, there are lots of canned regexes on the web that you can just search for rather than recreating them yourself which is what I did here.  I wouldn't have made it anywhere near that complex/specific.  You should adjust it to your needs, depending on how strict/liberal you want your matching.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem, but your regex is incorrect, try this

```
System.out.println("01/01/2012".replaceAll("(\\d+/){2}(.+)", "$2"));
```

Note that String.replace() does not work with regex. Use String.replaceAll() or String.replaceFirst() instead.

Comment: Google Refine does not recognizeSystem.out.println, and when I tried replaceChars("(\\d+/){2}(.+)", "$2")), the forward slashes between the numbers disappeared but nothing else changed.

Answer (score 0):

See the comma in your replace, the method over-loadings for that class expect either 3 strings or 1 string meaning no comma or two commas separating arguments to .replace() method.

Comment: Could you show me the corrected code then, please? Thank you!